Get package size for message on .NET6 with Grpc.Core
The gRPC logs produce the following log line:
2024-10-08 07:31:19.198 | VRB | Development | Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall | Deserializing 12259 byte message to '"MyMessage"'.

I need to implement a traffic counter.
So where can I hook in to et the value of the 12259 bytes and sum them?
I am using Grpc.Core 2.46.6 with .NET6.

You could perhaps subscribe to structured logging, listen for gRPC event 12, and capture the MessageLength value? https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/490894cdedb34b43c32dc576d5745c41223764b6/src/Grpc.AspNetCore.Server/Internal/GrpcServerLog.cs#L59 - there doesn't seem to be an explicit separate counter to track
